# How to save strings and integers permanently to a users device?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm building an app that requires the user to purchase content and sign to a User Agreement Contract. However, I'm not too sure where to start with in-app purchases and saving data types to the users device permanently. My initial idea for the UAC was like such:

`boolean ucaCheck;`
user clicks button to agree making `uacCheck = true;`

`if(uacCheck == false){`

starts UAC intent

`};`

But as you can see, I need the Boolean 'uacCheck' to be saved to the users device or the intent will start everytime the user starts the app.

I would like to do a similar thing for in-app purchases unless there is an easier way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-to-create-a-file-and-write-to-a-file-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You can store values on the user's device in several different ways.  [The "Storage Options" documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) is a good place to start.  Just be aware that anything you put on the device is not necessarily secure: the user owns the machine and may be able to read and modify any data you save to it.  If you want to save data about in-app purchases, it might be best to save that on your own server instead of locally, and have the app access it through an API.

Comment: Thanks! Assuming it was a smaller scale app that wouldn't have many purchases a month, would you think a home server would be worth it?

Comment: @kaio37k By "home server" do you mean "server run out of your home, on your personal Internet connection"?  Those are problematic for a number of reasons, including because most ISPs prohibit them in the standard service contract you signed.  For a small scale product, I'd set up the server on a cheap AWS or Google Cloud instance.

Comment: Yes, server run on my desktop. What languages would I need to learn for running a server on AWS or Google Cloud Instance?

Comment: @kaio37k Any language you would use to write a server for anything else.  AWS and Google Cloud are about hosting, not about languages or libraries.

Comment: Couldn't I just use Google's In-app Billing API?